# AnyChart more than one Floating Decimal points

Tags: anychart

I have create Anychart candlestick with 4 decimal point in Y axis. But It will automatically converted to single decimal point like (1.32444 to 1.3).

The chart source code is

```
$rootScope.$on('ReportCandleChartView', function (event, data) 
    {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () 
        {

            var dataTable = anychart.data.table();
            dataTable.addData(data);
            var mapping = dataTable.mapAs({'open': 1, 'high': 2, 'low': 3, 'close': 4});
            $rootScope.ch = anychart.stock();               
            var plot = $rootScope.ch.plot(0);



            plot.yGrid(true)
                .xGrid(true)
                .yMinorGrid(true)
                .xMinorGrid(true);
            var series = plot.candlestick(mapping);
            series.name($rootScope.globalChartsymbol);
            $rootScope.ch.scroller().candlestick(mapping);
            plot.yAxis().orientation('right');  
            var indicator1 = $rootScope.ch.plot(0).priceIndicator();
            indicator1.value('last-visible');     
            $rootScope.ch.container('containerxone');   
            $rootScope.ch.draw();

        });
    });
```

!https://ibb.co/mZN9YG
I've posted one Image that contain Anystock chart. On that we want to change the decimal point more than one digits.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following line before the chart creating code. It sets numbers of decimal for the whole chart.

```
anychart.format.locales.default.numberLocale.decimalsCount = 5;
```

Also, if you want to fill in the remaining decimal places zeros use then the following line:

```
anychart.format.locales.default.numberLocale.zeroFillDecimals = true;
```